# How to configure Rancher desktop to use existing Docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, rancher-desktop

I've a local Docker Desktop installation with local images for Redis, Elastic Search, MySQL etc. I want to move from Docker Desktop to Rancher Desktop. How can I configure Rancher Desktop to use already existing docker containers, images and volumes?

Is it even possible?